HuggingFace API for text generation: setting "num_beams" and using "past_key_values" when calling the method generate()
I have a piece of code to accelerate text generation using past_key_values. The simplified version is as follows:
prefix_output = model(prefix_input_ids)
generation_output = model.generate(postfix_input_ids, num_beams=1, use_cache=True, past_key_values=prefix_output.past_key_values)

Here the variable model can be GPT2LMHeadModel that has loaded gpt2-xl. The code works perfectly fine. The problem is that if num_beams is set to greater than 1, then I get the exception below (in the example I set num_beams to 3):

‘Sizes of tensors must match except in dimension 2. Expected size 1 but got size 3 for tensor number 1 in the list.’

I suspect that I should somehow pre-process the values of prefix_output.past_key_values, before passing it to model.generate(). I am not sure though. Anybody knows how to fix this? Thanks.
